# What if someone knows my iPhone passcode (not simple passcode) & restriction passcode?

Tags: ios, security, password, remote-control

Lets say I was just taking a walk or was in a train or a bus. I had to unlock my iPhone with passcode there and use the restriction passcode. Somehow a person saw me entering the passcode and I realised that I was watched and that was after a long time.

Can that person do anything like remote access (SSH, VNC) or something about encryption keys? Lets say that person has access to a backdoor to my cellular carrier & also knows my phone number (this means all my plain HTTP traffic, DNS queries, SMS, calls and other things can be seen, I am ignoring privacy policies here). What can that person do?

Comment: If you are facing an attacker which is able to connect to your phone via the mobile data network, you have bigger problems to worry about than whether he knows your passcode or not.

Comment: The kind of problems that would require changing at least your name & country of residence... ;)

Answer (score 3):

They can unlock your iPhone & remove the restrictions... assuming they ***have your iPhone*** as well as the passwords/codes.

Otherwise, nothing.

Comment: iphone's remote security doesnt anyhow depend on passcode? I mean knowing the passcode should be a bonus...it may help

Comment: The passcode unlocks the phone, nothing else. The restrictions passcode, the same, unlocks restrictions.

Comment: iPhones do not have remote access that can be 'hacked', as their entire software stack is encrypted, plus there is sandboxing. However if you jailbreak your phone, which means essentially disabling the encyrption, then yes, knowing your passcode a bad guy can do bad things remotely.